# Prove that if P(A) = P(A,B), then A is a subset of B.

Tags: probability, formal-proofs

I'm struggling a lot on this problem.

This feels intuitionistically true, since if their probabilities are equal, that means that the joint probability did not affect the size of the sample space that p maps to, which must mean that A is a subset.

How would I derive this from axioms?

Comment: What if $A$ is the event that a fair coin comes up heads and $B$ is the event that a two headed coin comes up heads?

Comment: By $P(A,B)$ do you mean $P(A \text{ and } B)$. If so this is not true in general, but it is 'almost' true. Specifically $A$ must be a subset of $B$ except for some set with probability $0$. You can prove this by using additivity of probability and the fact that $A \cap B$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $P(A)-P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap B^c)=0$, so $\omega\notin A\cap B^c$ for $P$-almost all $\omega$, which means that $A^c\cup B$ contains $P$-almost all $\omega$, or in other words, $(\omega\in A\implies\omega\in B)$ holds $P$-almost surely. By a slight abuse of language, one says that $A$ is almost surely included in $B$.